# Is it possible for RediSearch to use wildcards to get multiple JSON values at LOAD?

Tags: json, database, redis, aggregate, full-text-search

For an JSON-type object that has a shape like

```json
# myPrefix:myKey
{
  "inventory": [
    {
      "name": "Carrot",
      "desc": "A fresh vegetable"
    },
    {
      "name": "Knife",
      "desc": "A tool to cut things"
    }
  ]
}
```

it's possible to to get all `name`s in the `inventory` using JsonPath wildcards, like so: `JSON.GET myPrefix:myKey $.inventory[*].name` (or `$.inventory..name`), which would return `"[\"Carrot\",\"Knife\"]"`.

However, when trying to aggregate such data using RediSearch using `LOAD`, seemingly only the first value is returned. For example, after creating a search like `FT.CREATE mySearch ON JSON PREFIX 1 myPrefix: SCHEMA $.inventory[*].name as itemName TEXT`, attempting to aggregate with `FT.AGGREGATE mySearch * LOAD 2 @__key @itemName groupby 1 @__key reduce tolist 1 @itemName as itemsList` would return:

```
1) "1"
2) 1) "__key"
   2) "myPrefix:myKey"
   3) "itemsList"
   4) 1) "Carrot"
```

which ignores all other `itemName`s, apart from "Carrot".

Is it possible to query nested Json data in this way using the FT.AGGREGATE command, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

According to the FT.SEARCH documentation, it's possible to use a DIALECT setting to return several values: https://redis.io/commands/ft.search/#return-multiple-values

So an aggregation like `FT.AGGREGATE mySearch * LOAD 2 @__key @itemName GROUPBY 1 @__key REDUCE TOLIST 1 @itemName AS itemsList DIALECT 3` would correctly return :

```
1) "1"
2) 1) "__key"
   2) "myPrefix:myKey"
   3) "itemsList"
   4) 1) "[\"Carrot\",\"Knife\"]"
```